# Ember Handlebars nested each not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The following Ember Handlebars template renders the 1st row, but does not render the one inside the nested each (or inner each)

```
    <table width="50%">
        {{#each someData.items as |item|}}
            <tr> <!-- This one RENDERS -->
                <td width="25%"><span class="boldTxt">{{item.fld1}}</span></td>
                <td width="25%">{{item.fld2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{#each item.Reas as |rea|}}            
                <tr> <!-- This one does not RENDER -->
                    <td>{{rea}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>
```

What is the issue??

I am using Ember version 1.13

Comment: which ember version are you using?

Comment: What do your data look like? Remember that Ember doesn't support nested `@each` observers. Also, why are you using two different each syntaxes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember Handlebars Iterate object and display key inside nested each helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544579/ember-handlebars-iterate-object-and-display-key-inside-nested-each-helper)

Comment: it is actually different

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your problem is that you are using **Ember2.0** or above (based on your outer `each` loop) so your inner `each` loop has a now invalid (formerly deprecated) format. Also, you are using the same variable name `item` for both loops, which won't work properly.

[http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/](http://Helpful%20Link)

Just use the same format as in the outer loop:

Change:

```
{{#each item in item.Reasons}}
```

To:

```
{{#each item.Reasons as |reason|}}
```

---

#### EDIT

If your `Reas` arrays look as you've described in the comments:

```
item.Reas = [null]; // arrays containing a single `null` value
```

Then handlebars will show an empty string for these values since Handlebars coerces `undefined` and `null` to an empty string.

```
{{reas}} {{!-- if reas is null then an empty string is printed --}
```

If you want to show `null` and `undefined` values, you can make a simple helper to do so:

```
// helpers/show-value.js
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {
  let value = params[0];

  if(value === undefined) { return 'undefined'; }
  if(value === null) { return 'null'; }
  return value;

});
```

---

#### EDIT 2

*Based on your explanation in the comment:*

Since you are using Ember 1.13, you need a work around to achieve this. Here is one way:

```
// components/each-keys.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  object: null, // passed in object
  items: Ember.computed('object', function() {
    var object = Ember.get(this, 'object');

    var keys = Ember.keys(object);

    return keys.map(function(key) {
      return { key: key, value: object[key]};
    })
  })
})
```

Usage:

```
{{#each-keys object=item.Reas as |key value|}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each-keys}}
```

[**Here is a running example**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rwjblue/388/edit?html,css,js,output)

If you update to Ember 2.0, which should be pretty straightforward from 1.13 (since 2.0 is basically 1.13 without deprecations) you can use the [`each-in`](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_each-in-helper) helper to iterate over an object and get access to both its keys and values. Here is a simple example:

```
{{#each-in items as |key value|}}
  <p>{{key}}: {{value}}</p>
{{/each-in}}
```

Comment: Thx...I am using Ember version 1.13 ...let me try ur code

Comment: it is still not working with the updated each statement...using {{#each as }} syntax for both inner/outer each now

Comment: I just tried your example code in twiddle and it's working for me. Here is the link: https://ember-twiddle.com/8cd8554497027e23dbb5. If it's still not working for you, then can you please share your code in an ember-twiddle?

Comment: which version does it uses ? Also my JSON structure is slightly different and I want to print the object key itself

Comment: My JSON looks like Reasons: {
           "Reason - 1": [null],
          "Reason - 2": [null]
        }

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your code in a pen/box/fiddle or something like that? I am not sure why it's not working

Comment: Wait, your reason arrays contain a single element which is a `null` value?

Comment: Thx...while my Reasons is actually an object with 2 key/value pairs as shown; Reasons: { "Reason - 1": [null], "Reason - 2": [null] }

...But I want to print the keys i.e. Reason - 1 & Reason - 2 (and not the key values i.e. null array )

Comment: Well each-in does not work for Ember version < 2...Even in the link you posted, it is under EMBER 2.0 BETA

Comment: It seems there is no solution to get each-in working for Ember ver < 2

Comment: @testndtv yeah, you're right, each-in is available only in Ember > 2.0, but I edited a possible workaround you can use as suggested by one of the Ember core team members